# React Native CLI - How to debug Redux on the device?

Tags: react-native, redux, bluetooth, react-native-cli, react-native-ble-plx

I am building a Bluetooth app (using [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and Redux).

When the app is running in the simulator, I can debug the Redux state with [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). But Bluetooth is not available in the simulator, so I have to build the app every time I want to see my changes (correct me if I am doing wrong). But now I don't know how to debug the Redux state when I test my app on the device. Any suggestion there?

Comment: Reactotron and Flipper both have plugins for inspecting Redux state and viewing dispatched actions

Comment: Are you running a regular debug build on your device, or a release build? A debug build should be able to use bluetooth and also connect to your debugger